# How to disable auto mount on ubuntu live disk?

Tags: live-usb, 15.04

I'm trying to boot an Ubuntu 15.04 usb stick to recover my hard disks, but one of the first operations that the live distro performs during boot, is to mount my disks, which cannot be mounted and the boot stops. I choose "try Ubuntu" from the live usb menu.

Is there a way to stop the automount during boot?

I need to perform some btrfsck on the disks, and they must be unmounted. So I actually need them not to be mounted during boot.

Comment: Can you not unmount them after boot?

Comment: The boot process fails when trying to mount the hard disks.

Comment: Can you physically disconnect them?

Comment: Yes, but can I "hot reconnect" after boot? They are normal SATA disks (WD RED on an Intel Atom-based mainboard)

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure... In what way does boot fail? Is it still trying to use them to boot?

Comment: If your BIOS supports hot-swap of SATA devices (the majority of BIOSes does), its fine to hot-plug it.

Comment: I managed to boot the live ubuntu, after finding out which drive was blocking the mount, so I disconnected it. Then, after boot, the hot connect worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Tim if you provide an answer based on your comment about hot plugging, I will be pleased to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim: I agree (my answer deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disconnect the drive, then boot.

Hopefully your BIOS supports hot plugging - most BIOSes do.